# forget password and remember me?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a login screen, im simply doing login.
i need to add remember me and forget password functionality  to it.
what should i do?

my controoler:

```
            angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

             .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, authService, $state, $http)
              {

        $scope.loginSubmitted = false;
        $scope.myflag = false;
          $scope.user = {};
       $scope.userData = {};

         $scope.doLogin = function() {

     $scope.present = 0;
     authService.GetByUsername().success(function(data) {
    $scope.userData = data;
    console.log($scope.userData);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.userData.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.userData[i].username == $scope.user.userName &&        $scope.userData[i].password == $scope.user.Password) {

        $scope.loginstatus=1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if($scope.loginstatus==1){
      $state.go('app.single')
    }
    else {
        console.log('wrong credentials');
      }

  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


}



      })
```

if its not possible to code, give me the clear idea, or steps i need to follow.

Comment: you need `localStorage` to remember user state after login, and forgot password will be done on server, since its required you to make a call to api `auth/recover` with `email`, after that server sends an email with reset token on registered email, where user can click on link and reset password in browser

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for Remember-Me functionality..

https://blog.craigpalermo.com/tutorial/angularjs/2015/05/26/remember-me-angularjs.html

Comment: Not now but you can download example from bellow link as a reference to get more help..https://github.com/gmarland/angularjs-nodejs-passportjs-rememberMe